# Camel, parameterized query and converter

Tags: sql, spring, apache-camel

I'm newbie in Camel, I would like to known if it's possible to convert a Camel header message value before to pass it to a parameterized query ? I use Camel and Spring boot.

In below example, I would like the object "o" to be converted automatically into string, for example, and injected into the query.

from("direct:test").setHeader("y", o).to("sql:select * from x where a = :#y")

It's possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from("direct:test").setHeader("y", o).to("bean:someBean?method=somePublicMethod").to("sql:select * from x where a = ${body}")
```

Write a bean class  with id someBean or just name the class as SomeBean and inside that write a public method called somePublicMethod. Inside that you can convert and set the result to camel message body.  Something like this

```
public void handleFiegeReadyEvent(Exchange exchange){
    exchange.getIn().getBody(); // retrieve the body of the message from previous stage. Cat it ti appropriate type.
    // do whatever you want to do here and generate the result
    exchange.getIn().setBody(result);
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("key1", value1);
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("key2", value2);  
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to do it implicitly. Configure camel to do it consistently ?

Comment: you can use `convertBodyTo(String.class)`. But doing like this will give you more control. `rom("direct:test").setHeader("y", o).convertBodyTo(String.class).to("sql:select * from x where a = :#y")`

Comment: That solution doesn't work in my case because I would like to use header values and I can have several headers values to inject in my sql query

Comment: You can set multiple header values in the method is specified above and then access using `${in.header.key}`

Comment: OK, I will use this solution. Thanks